# How to multi substitute with single argument

Tags: python

The code below:

```
a = 'value'
b = '%s %s %s'%a
```

results to:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How to insert the same value stored in `a` to declare `b`?

Comment: What do you want to get? `b = a`?

Comment: for illustration purposes. The goal is to insert the same value multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [`str.format()`](https://pyformat.info/) instead:

```
>>> a = 'value'
>>> b = '{0} {0} {0}'.format(a)
>>> b
'value value value'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use named parameters:

```
print("{a} {a} {a}".format(a="value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I love to use the below format:

```
a = 'value'
b = '%s %s %s' % (a, a, a)
```

Output:

```
value value value
```